Can multiple people deploy to Vercel on Github via pushing to main?
I have a Next.js project that I deploy to Hobby Vercel and my project is in Github.
I and one other person are pushing to the main branch. My account is linked to Vercel and currently, only my pushes to main are deployed to Vercel. My Grandpa's commits also push to the main branch and are not automatically deployed. He uses his own Github account.
How do I ensure that his commits are also directly deployed via Vercel? Is it even possible with the free tier Vercel plan?
Apparently, only the pushes to main with the Github account linked to the Vercel project are currently automatically deployed

You can trigger a deploy by hitting this deploy hook which can be created at
Projects > Settings > Git > Deploy Hooks
You can use any CI like GitHub actions to hit this hook or open this link in a browser whenever you need a deployment.
Deploying via Vercel automation requires paid seat.
